# Python indentation; Tab = 4*whitespace?

Tags: python, indentation

Another identation-question but i didn't find this particular one anywhere so here goes.

Is there some simple way, or some good editor, that lets me use tab to create a 4*whitespace identation instead of the hardtab jump?

I really want to be able to use tab while coding, but i want it to conform to the 4 whitespace standard.

Comment: There's loads of editors with loads of options... Have a look at http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonEditors for some, and feel free to experiment and take your pick. This isn't really a question for SO though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a feature called "soft tabs", many editors offer it. Go for google ;)

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ (Windows), Sublime Text, vim (Unix/Linux) etc. There are a lot of them